# GC overhead limit exceeded when loading a mongodb collection in scala

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, intellij-idea, garbage-collection

I am trying to load a mongodb collection in scala. The collection contains 105356 entries, and a total size of 115MB. This is an example of what one entry in the file contains:

```
{
    "_id" : 1635402,
    "authentified" : true,
    "sessions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("592bea0f000000000049964e"),
            "authentified" : true,
            "actions" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("592beaaa000000000000062f"),
                    "item" : 1583,
                    "acType" : "VIEW"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59c135f20000000000625ebc"),
            "authentified" : true,
            "actions" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59c136a00000000000000d29"),
                    "item" : 3369,
                    "acType" : "VIEW"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("59c136dc0000000000000ae5"),
                    "item" : 2789,
                    "acType" : "VIEW"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Scala in the intellij IDE 2017.2.6, and here is my main object:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster("local[*]")
    conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "10g")
    conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")
    conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    val db = client.getDatabase("MyDB")

    val users = sc.makeRDD(db.getCollection("user").find().results(500))
    println(users.collect().size)
  }
}
```

The function results is defined as follow:

```
def results(time: Int): Seq[C] = Await.result(observable.toFuture(), Duration(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

Concerning dependencies I am using:

```
<scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
```

and:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb.scala</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-scala-driver_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-remote_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

As you can see I am doing this in local, I modified thz VM options in the run configuration by adding **-Xms512m -Xmx4g -Xss32m**, and in the meun **file>settings>Compiler> Build process heap size (Mbyte)** I put **3000**.

When I run my App I receive an error of type: *GC overhead limit exceeded*:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$$resolveTry(Promise.scala:47)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:244)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.failure(Promise.scala:104)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.failure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable$$anonfun$toFuture$2.apply(ObservableImplicits.scala:340)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable$$anonfun$toFuture$2.apply(ObservableImplicits.scala:340)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable$$anon$1.onError(ObservableImplicits.scala:98)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ToSingleObservable$$anon$3.onError(ObservableImplicits.scala:414)
    at org.mongodb.scala.internal.MapObservable$$anon$1.onError(MapObservable.scala:26)
    at org.mongodb.scala.internal.SubscriptionCheckingObserver.onError(SubscriptionCheckingObserver.scala:36)
    at org.mongodb.scala.internal.FoldLeftObservable$$anon$1.onError(FoldLeftObservable.scala:34)
    at org.mongodb.scala.internal.SubscriptionCheckingObserver.onError(SubscriptionCheckingObserver.scala:36)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.onError(AbstractSubscription.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription$2.onResult(MongoIterableSubscription.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoIterableSubscription$2.onResult(MongoIterableSubscription.java:87)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:252)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:235)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$1.onResult(DefaultServer.java:185)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol$CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandProtocol.java:275)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:23)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:470)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$2.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:464)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$3.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:119)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$3.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.executeCallbackAndReceiveResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:378)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1700(InternalStreamConnection.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseBuffersCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:420)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseBuffersCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:389)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback.onSuccess(InternalStreamConnection.java:562)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback.access$2200(InternalStreamConnection.java:517)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback$ResponseBodyCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:584)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$ResponseHeaderCallback$ResponseBodyCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:568)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:447)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$3.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:444)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:201)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:281)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ReadTask.completed(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:579)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:397)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:47)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec.readValue(BsonArrayCodec.java:102)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec.decode(BsonArrayCodec.java:67)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec.decode(BsonArrayCodec.java:37)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:47)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec.readValue(BsonArrayCodec.java:102)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec.decode(BsonArrayCodec.java:67)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonArrayCodec.decode(BsonArrayCodec.java:37)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.ImmutableDocumentCodec.decode(ImmutableDocumentCodec.scala:62)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.ImmutableDocumentCodec.decode(ImmutableDocumentCodec.scala:38)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:52)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:53)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:47)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:56)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ReplyMessage.<init>(ReplyMessage.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.getResponseDocument(CommandProtocol.java:139)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.access$000(CommandProtocol.java:51)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol$CommandResultCallback.callCallback(CommandProtocol.java:271)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ResponseCallback.onResult(ResponseCallback.java:23)
```

I am wondering why such configurations is not enough to load such a small collection of 115MB?

Comment: Can you please post the exact stack trace?

Comment: Now it is done, I edited the question by adding error details, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by changing the VM options from

**-Xms512m -Xmx4g -Xss32m**

to

**-Xms512m -Xmx14g -Xss32m**

ie. by using 14gb in stead of 4gb (it loads now in 27 seconds).

In addition; using **-Xss64m**, it finishes it is loaded in 26 seconds.

Comment: tamuz, wouldn't changing Spark memory options from `10g` to `4g` (i.e. the one that matches your `-Xmx` JVM setting) fix the issue as well? At the first glance it looks like data should be able to fit into 4GB but you said Spark to use up to 10GB and it tries to do so but JVM can't provide that much.